# If $f:\Bbb{R}^{+}\times \Bbb{R}^{n}\to \Bbb{R}^{n}$is continuous, then prove that the solution of $f$ exists on $\Bbb{R}^+$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm very new to ODE in $\Bbb{R}^n$, so it might take some time to get used to proofs in this area. For now, I'm faced with this problem:

Let $\Vert\;\Vert$ be the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$. Let $x:[0,a]\to \Bbb{R}^n$ be differentiable. We consider the following O.D.E

\begin{align}\begin{cases}x'(t)=f(t,x(t)) & t\geq 0,\\x(0)=x_0\in \Bbb{R}^n&\end{cases}\end{align}
where \begin{align}f:\Bbb{R}^{+}\times \Bbb{R}^{n}\to \Bbb{R}^{n}\end{align}is continuous such that $\langle x,f(t,x)\rangle\leq 0,\;\forall\;t\geq 0,\;x\in\Bbb{R}^n.$ 
So, how do I prove that the solution of $f$ exists on $\Bbb{R}^+?$ Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: You may find some useful information under the topic of "existence of solutions to ODE". There is  information about this fundmanetal topic, in every textbook ever written on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existence for a short time is given by Peano's Theorem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem

Existence for any $t\geq0$ usually needs $f$ to be locally Lipschitz, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Global_uniqueness_and_maximum_domain_of_solution
Let us assume you have that. The only way the solution ceases to exist at a time $T_0$, is by 'blowing up', i.e. $\|x(t)\|\rightarrow\infty$ for $t\rightarrow T_0$.
Let us take a look at
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\|x(t)\|^2)=2\langle x',x\rangle=2\langle f(t,x(t)),x(t)\rangle\leq 0.$$
Hence $\|x(t)\|$ is monotonically decreasing and therefore $\|x(t)\|\leq \|x(0)\|$. Hence it cannot blow up.